# Unsupported browser notification in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, cross-browser

I'm using ruby on rails to develop this webapp that only supports the latest browser.

How do i show a pop-up message when user is using unsupported browser.
The message will show when the page is not loaded in the following browser:

1. Firefox 4 and above
2. IE9 and above
3. Safari 5 and above
4. Chrome 10 and above

Comment: What features do you need that these lower versions don't have? Alert the user when their browser doesn't support the feature, not when they have the wrong kind of browser.

Comment: HTML 5 and CSS 3. Noted thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery Browser Rejection Plugin](https://github.com/TurnWheel/jReject) can help you. it supports following browsers disable/enable options:

```
        msie: false,msie5: true,msie6: true,msie7: false,msie8: false, // MSIE Flags (Global, 5-8)
        firefox: false,firefox1: false,firefox2: false,firefox3: false, // Firefox Flags (Global, 1-3)
        konqueror: false,konqueror1: false,konqueror2: false,konqueror3: false, // Konqueror Flags (Global, 1-3)
        chrome: false,chrome1: false,chrome2: false,chrome3: false,chrome4: false, // Chrome Flags (Global, 1-4)
        safari: false,safari2: false,safari3: false,safari4: false, // Safari Flags (Global, 1-4)
        opera: false,opera7: false,opera8: false,opera9: false,opera10: false, // Opera Flags (Global, 7-10)
        gecko: false,webkit: false,trident: false,khtml: false,presto: false, // Rendering Engines (Gecko, Webkit, Trident, KHTML, Presto)
        win: false,mac: false,linux : false,solaris : false,iphone: false, // Operating Systems (Win, Mac, Linux, Solaris, iPhone)
        unknown: false // Unknown covers everything else
```

Comment: which js file should i change if i want to disable/enable a certain version of browser?

Comment: this is the settings for the plugin. you need to update your application layout with **$(function() { $.reject(); });**

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple using [jreject_rails](http://rubygems.org/gems/jreject_rails) gem

Just need to call function into your javascript file.

$(function() {
  $.reject({
    reject: {
      msie5: true,
      msie6: true,
      msie7: true
    }
  });
});

Make those versions true which your site don't support.

Let me know If you any issue to implement. It works for me.